# CryENGINE: Remove the default gun and put another thing?

Tags: cryengine

I'm using CryEngine for a game that I'm working on for a while but it is not an FPS  (it's a Sandbox) then I would remove the gun and put another thing (example: a shovel)

Comment: You already asked this question, you've not added any additional information to this question. You need to add additional information about what you've tried and what hasn't worked. Give people a starting point to answer your question from. It ensures that you and the answerer are on the same page, so you can get the answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this. You can follow the documentation found under [First Person Weapons](http://freesdk.crydev.net/display/SDKDOC3/First-Person+Weapons). The definition of such an item would be created using information found in the [Weapon System](http://freesdk.crydev.net/display/SDKDOC4/Weapon+System) documentation. Overall, the steps are as follows:

1. Model a weapon/shovel through 3dsmax/maya.
2. Make animations for the item through 3dsmax/maya.
3. Export the item and animations using the [CryEnigne 3 exporter](http://freesdk.crydev.net/display/SDKDOC3/Exporting+the+Character+into+CryENGINE).
4. Make a xml file for your tool.